# Android: Is there any way to identify when the keys are pressed/unpressed on an edittext softkeyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an autocomplete edittext field that sends queries to a server everytime the text changes, however if the user types a lot of text and then holds down "delete" I don't want to send a query for every single character deleted. One way of getting around this would be to cache all the queries as the characters were entered and then play back the cache on deletion - but that seems to me to be unnecessarily complicated. An easier way is to detect keydown/keyup and then only send a query if the text has changed but the user also isn't touching the keyboard. Which leads me to the difficulty of how to catch keyup from a softkeyboard.

I've already tried ontouchlistener (doesn't fire) and onkeypressedlistener (also doesnt fire) and even overriding onKeyPreIme inside the edittext (also doesn't fire). Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution was to combine Andrea's answer with Jelle's. I record the last time a key was pressed in a textwatcher and only test against it 500 ms after that - in order to know for sure that it was the last key pressed:

```
private static long lastCharacterPress = 0l;
private Editable stringToSearchFor;
private Handler delayedCharacterCheck;

    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            lastCharacterPress = System.currentTimeMillis();
            stringToSearchFor = s;

            if (s.length() > 2) {

                delayedCharacterCheck.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        checkIfTimeHasPassed();
                    }
                }, 500);

            } else ...

        }
    });
```

then I put in this method:

```
private void checkIfTimeHasPassed() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(stringToSearchFor) && edittext.getText().length() > 2 && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCharacterPress > 499) {
                // perform the actual query
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed this problem is to add a delay to the query so it won't execute every time. My code looked something like this:

```
long lastPress = 0l;
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
         int start, int before, int count){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastpress > 500){
        lastPress= System.currentTimeMillis();
        // insert query here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks - this works mostly. Now if the user types 50 characters and then deletes them the query is only triggered about a fifth as often, although unfortunately still multiple times.

Comment: @Jon 500ms is for a phone not much. You can make the delay 700/800ms without experiencing any problems

Comment: this still has a disadvantage in that if a user types in 3 characters (or however many to pass 500ms) a search already starts executing - but if the user types in one character more than that, then the search that has already started will ignore the last character (less than x ms since search began) - so the results returned are wrong. Essentially, if a user is typing in a string that is one/two character longer than the time it takes for the search to start then the search will be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can't detect it directly, but you could find an indirect way by overriding the onMeasure in your Activity and detecting when it shrinks and expand over a certain threshold, as long as you define in your Manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode` to be `adjustResize`.

In my experience, though, the method is not extremely reliable. You should also consider that the user may leave your activity without closing the keyboard.

It depends on what kind of action you need to take upon deletion, but I was in a similar case where I needed to save the edited text to a shared preference. I found that the best solution is to save it at every character deletion: it's the only safe and consistent method I've found and the performance hit is not noticeable.

Comment: Well, if the user deletes some characters, but not all of them, then I want to send a new query with the partial string to get a new resultset for the user. If the user deletes all the characters then I won't do anything. The problem is that since the app can't tell if the user is holding down delete to get rid of anything or only deleting a few characters, it has to send a query for every change of characters just to be sure - which is a huge waste.

Comment: @Jon, It is indeed a huge waste, but in some cases (especially if your action happens locally) that waste creates a performance loss that is not noticeable. Otherwise, you could try to delay the action of a few milliseconds and in case any other request has been made in the mean time, you ignore the first one. But in any case, I think that detecting when the keyboard is shown or hide is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `TextWatcher`

1)Create one `TextWatcher` listener object :

```
 private static long time = 0;
 private final  long TIME_DELAY = 700;

 private final TextWatcher myTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time > TIME_DELAY ){
            time= System.currentTimeMillis();
           // your codes 
           } 

        }
    };
```

2)Register this listener to your `edittext`

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

Comment: thanks - I'm using a textwatcher. However, this doesn't tell me when the keyboard is being pressed and when it isn't. If a user holds down delete after entering 50 characters, textwatcher will fire 50 times - once for every character deleted. I need it to fire only once at the end.

Comment: Yes, for security reason, android doesnot provide any informations regarding keyboard events. For this case you have mentioned, i think it will be better if you will add one time limit for firing your event. i.e. if user will wait for a little time after typing one letter, trigger your event to server. Don't start it if he is pressing or typing continuously.

Comment: I can get the time when the last character was input with little difficulty - I just record it in a textwatcher. The issue is how to regularly test against that time in order to know if more than X time has passed since the last character was input. The only way I can think of is to have another thread running continually in a loop, testing the time - but I think that could cause several problems in and of itself.

Comment: Use static variable to record the time when key is entered. That way it will be same for all objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to identify the **delete** key pressed in the **softkeyboard** then try this..

```
final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
edit1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value 
        // with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ 
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            // this is for backspace 
            Log.e("IME_TEST", "DEL KEY");
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: onKeyListener works only for the hardware keyboards and not the soft keyboards.

Comment: thanks. It doesn't matter for me so much to know which key is pressed - only whether any key is being pressed or whether nothing is being pressed. Then, if the user holds down the delete key, the search will only happen once when the user stops touching the keypad.